# Create arbitrary X509 extensions with M2Crypto

Tags: python, x509, m2crypto

I'm interested in creating a CSR that contains arbitrary extensions, specified by an OID. Ideally, I'd like the value to be an ASN1-encoded entity, though setting it to a string is enough.

Various online examples point to code such as this:

```
extensionStack = X509.X509_Extension_Stack()
extension = X509.new_extension('subjectAltName', 'DNS:example.com')
extensionStack.push(extension)
request.add_extensions(extensionStack)
```

The extension is created from a predefined name like `subjectAltName`, which is then mapped to the right OID. Apparently, these strings are defined in [objects.txt](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/52f71f8181f1cb090bc4ee5070450cd07a1aea21/crypto/objects/objects.txt), and there's no way to add your own, except by recompiling OpenSSL.

[The documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY_EXTENSIONS) says that custom X509 extensions can be added by editing `openssl.cnf`. However, my understanding is that this will affect only operations that invoke OpenSSL from the command line.

How to do the same with M2Crypto? In other words, how to make it work more or less like this?

```
X509.new_extension('OID:1.2.3.4.5.42', 'test')
#or this
X509.new_extension('OID:1.2.3.4.5.42', '0x1E4...819')
```

Comment: "...a CSR that contains arbitrary extensions..." - though your CSR contains them, it does not mean the issuer will copy them into the cert they issue for you. Most issuers tend to be fairly rigid about what gets copied and signed.

Comment: That's true, but this is for an internally developed system, so it is a fact that the CA will accept and include them in the issued certificate.

Comment: OK, I missed that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it:

```
ext = X509.new_extension('1.2.3.4', 
                         'ASN1:UTF8String:Some random data')
# If required: ext.set_critical(1)
cert.add_ext(ext)
```

It will appear in the OpenSSL dump:

```
                1a:91:ca:bf:aa:ba:3b:49:57
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:foobar.example.com
        1.2.3.4: 
            ..Some random data
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    18:24:4c:42:fe:7c:71:a6:58:ed:be:9d:2e:9e:ea:a7:80:0f:
```

Unfortunately, M2Crypto has a problem retrieving custom extensions unless they were to be registered first, and those functions aren't currently exposed through M2Crypto. The name and value will come back as "UNDEF" and "None", respectively.

Comment: This works, thank you. I must admit that after failing to find a way to do this, I solved the problem by manually creating the ASN1 structure using `pyasn1` and then computing the signature using M2Crypto's primitives. This worked well, but boy... what a detour I have made... If someone else is interested, this is the syntax definition: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ASN1_generate_nconf.html#

Comment: Hmm, I am having a hard time finding a way to give it an existing, DER encoded structure. According to http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY_EXTENSIONS , this ought to work `ext = X509.new_extension('1.2.3.4', 'ASN1:DER:010203')`. Is there any trick that has to be performed to feed it such data?

Comment: I would assume that you're going to be sunk if you want to step out of the one or two extension-related use-cases that *M2Crypto* was built for. My own path of least resistance is to use my CA to maintain a tree of certificates with "otherName" UTF8 strings under subjectAltName extensions. I'm using *pyasn1* to read the extensions (since *M2Crypto* uses *OpenSSL*, and *OpenSSL* is hardcoded to return the literal "unsupported" for *otherName* values). I'm *still* trying to decode the DER-encoded octet-strings back to being human-readable using *pyasn1*...